# Video editing performance

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, performance

I'm trying to edit a video using Blender and the video playback is really slow for some reason.  The input video is 3 AVI clips all resampled to 25fps. They were all different framerates, so I used another program to resample them to all be the same so they'd sync.

I've built proxy frames for all 3 tracks at 25% and even tried reducing their JPEG quality to 50%.

In the preview, I get about 4 to 6 fps so the video doesn't keep up with the audio.  If I set the sync to either of the two options other than No Sync, the video freezes for seconds at a time.

I had an old version of Blender so I just updated to the latest official build yesterday but that didn't make any difference.

My system is a couple years old and not exactly top-of-the-line, but it doesn't suck (usually).  It's got a 4Ghz AMD FX-8370 8 core processor (8 logical cores, 4 actual cores), 16Gig of RAM, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750, and everything is on an SSD. And Windows 10.

The video is rendering as I write this.  CPU utilization is about 8%, memory only about 32%. Disk activity only about 1% and GPU about 8%.  So it doesn't seem to be hardware bound.

Is there some setting I should adjust to get better results?

Comment: You "built proxy frames for all 3 tracks." Did you also set the [proxy render size](https://i.imgur.com/4tyPR7O.jpg) in the preview window?

Comment: "video playback is really slow for some reason"... Blender's VSE is a very primitive and inefficient tool. Try using a dedicated video editing app like resolve free, shotcut, avid media composer first, or some of the paid ones like premiere or vegas... Those apps are optimized to use better use of your hardware and you can avoid having to transcode to unify framerates or having to work with proxies.